# JS to coffeescript not working in my rails 3 app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

I have some JS that works fine for me when added directly in my view...

```
  #app/views/registrations/index.html.erb
...
    <td><%= check_box_tag 'checked_in', registration.id , registration.checked_in, :class => "check-in" %></td>
...
     <script>
    $(".check-in").bind('change', function(){
        $.ajax({
          url: '/registrations/'+this.value+'/toggle',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {"checked_in": this.checked}
        });
    });
      </script>
```

Rendered html is...

```
<td><input checked="checked" class="check-in" id="checked_in" name="checked_in" type="checkbox" value="5" /></td>
```

I went to http://js2coffee.org/ and ran it through the grinder and it gave me...

```
$(".check-in").bind "change", ->
  $.ajax
    url: "/registrations/" + @value + "/toggle"
    type: "POST"
    data:
      checked_in: @checked
```

So I added this chunk to app/assets/javascripts/registrations.js.coffee and no worky. No errors are being thrown in firefox web console, and if I view source on the page the JS is not being generated/displayed. However, if I do something like alert "Test" in the registrations.js.coffee file, I do see it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Comma missing after each key/value pair?

Comment: Could you be more specific? A pastebin perhaps?

Comment: @Lumbee Are you including the revised `<script src>` in the same location as the original? It may now be running before any `.check-in` elements actually exist. Try adding a [`$ ->`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) on the 1st line and indenting the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was originally in

> `app/views/registrations/index.html.erb`

but the CoffeeScript version went into the asset-pipeline as

> `app/assets/javascripts/registrations.js.coffee`

The `app/assets` scripts will be loaded at the top of the page so when `$(".check-in")` is executed, there won't be any `.check-in` elements to bind to and nothing useful happens. You need a document-ready wrapper:

```
$ ->
  $(".check-in").bind "change", ->
    $.ajax
      url: "/registrations/#{@value}/toggle"
      type: "POST"
      data:
        checked_in: @checked
```

to get things running at the right time.

Comment: Still no worky. Any way for me to test if is loading after the page is displayed. Checked page source and I don't see any JS there.

Comment: You won't see the JS in the page, it will be pulled in through a `<script src="...">` tag. You do have something in your layouts for pulling in `application.js`, right?

Comment: Correct, I have a js include tag that is pulling application.js. I am able to do an alert statement in my registrations.js.coffee file and it correctly fires, so I think we are OK on that.

Comment: You're sure you have a `.check-in` on the page when it loads? Is this Rails4/Turbolinks?

Comment: Yes, just updated the view in my original question to include the erb in my view.

Comment: Are your assets getting compiled properly? Anything stuck in the caches?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45831/discussion-between-lumbee-and-mu-is-too-short)

Comment: OK, so I guess it was an assets problem. I did an assets precompile, and that fixed the the issue. WTF? I thought if I was running in pre-compiled assets should not be an issue!